# Cucumber - Java - Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/plugin/ConcurrentEventListener

Tags: noclassdeffounderror, event-listener, cucumber-java

I've tried searching for the specific error. Though there have been few questions answered for java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError I could not find one for io/cucumber/plugin/ConcurrentEventListener.

- I am creating a basic cucumber test to login to a public website
- I have implemented a separate webconnector module to handle driver operations using pico-container
- I understand there is something wrong with the dependencies added to pom.xml but not able to zero in on the root cause.

When I run the scenario from feature file (and even with the runner) I keep getting below error when running the test.

I'll appreciate any help or pointers on the problem I'm facing. Thank you.

**Stacktrace:**

*

```
***Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/cucumber/plugin/ConcurrentEventListener**
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.loadClass(PluginFactory.java:174)
    at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.pluginClass(PluginFactory.java:166)
    at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.getPluginClass(PluginFactory.java:223)
    at cucumber.runtime.formatter.PluginFactory.isStepDefinitionReporterName(PluginFactory.java:206)
    at io.cucumber.core.options.RuntimeOptionsBuilder$ParsedPluginData.addPluginName(RuntimeOptionsBuilder.java:213)
    at io.cucumber.core.options.RuntimeOptionsBuilder.addPluginName(RuntimeOptionsBuilder.java:61)
    at io.cucumber.core.options.RuntimeOptionsParser.parse(RuntimeOptionsParser.java:90)
    at io.cucumber.core.options.CommandlineOptionsParser.parse(CommandlineOptionsParser.java:25)
    at io.cucumber.core.options.CommandlineOptionsParser.parse(CommandlineOptionsParser.java:29)
    at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.run(Main.java:29)
    at io.cucumber.core.cli.Main.main(Main.java:14)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.cucumber.plugin.ConcurrentEventListener
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:355)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 23 more
Process finished with exit code 1*
```

*

**My pom.xml:**

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>7</source>
                    <target>7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
<!--        Selenium Dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        Selenium Drivers -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-ie-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-edge-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.14.0</version>
        </dependency>
<!--        Cucumber Dependencies-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-picocontainer</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.masterthought</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-reporting</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.13.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
            <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

**The test runner:**

```
package Runners;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
        dryRun = false,
        strict = true,
        monochrome = true,
        features = {"src/test/resources/features"},
        glue = {"StepDefs","WebConnector"},
        plugin = {
                "pretty"
        }
)
public class Runner {
}
```

And the sample feature file:

```
Feature: User logs into the account on National Rail
  Background: Browser set up
  Given The browser is launched Chrome
  Scenario Outline: User successfully logs in to the account
    Given I am on Home page
    And I enter login credentials <User_Id>,<Password>
    Examples:
    | User_Id |Password  |
    | UserId1 |password1 |
    | UserId2 |password2 |
```

Comment: You have way too much info here. Try to create an MCVE by going through the tutorials and triangulate from there https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/10-minute-tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try upgrading all the Cucumber dependencies to v5, you seem to have v5 of `gherkin` but rest of them are v4.

If you check github, there's no ConcurrentEventListener for [v4](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/v4.8.1/plugin/src/main/java/io/cucumber/plugin/ConcurrentEventListener.java) but there's one for [v5](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/v5.0.0/plugin/src/main/java/io/cucumber/plugin/ConcurrentEventListener.java)

I believe, this should resolve your issue.

Comment: Please note that the Gherkin version used by a particular Cucumber-jvm version does not have to match the version of cucumber-jvm itself. Gherkin is a transitive dependency of cucumber-jvm.

Answer (score 1):

1. Please make sure to use the same version for all of your Cucumber dependencies.

You are currently mixing `<version>4.8.1</version>` and `<version>5.0.0</version>`.

2. Please make sure to only specify the (Cucumber) dependencies you actually need. Some dependencies (e.g. Gherkin) are transitive, meaning they are provided by the Cucumber dependencies you specify.

You can find more on which dependencies to use (and their latest version) in the [Cucumber docs](https://cucumber.io/docs/installation/java/)

Comment: Thanks, similar to previous answer I have upgraded cucumber dependencies to 5 and that solved the issue. I will remove the transitive dependencies to keep it tidy.